# jquery selectors with option (select) throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed this after a user reported the behavior since it was working fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE8+. However in IE7 the following selectors:

```
$('#parentjobs option')
$('#parentjobs option:not(:contains("new"))')
```

throw this error:

```
Error: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

Which points to line 5126 on jquery-1.8.3:

```
context = Expr.find["ID"]( token.matches[0].replace( rbackslash, "" ), context, xml )[0];
```

I don't have IE7 installed but I can reproduce the error when I switch the document mode and browser mode to IE7 on the IE debug page (F12)

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that in IE7 and below `getElementById` is **not** case-sensitive which was the cause of my problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx

In IE8 Standards mode, `getElementById` performs a case-sensitive match on theID attribute only.
In IE7 Standards mode and previous modes, this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the ID and NAME attributes, which might produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but something that might make it work cross-browser, in a different way, is to use `filter`:

```
$("#parentjobs").find("option").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("new") === -1;
});
```

Which says "only include the `<option>` elements that don't contain the text 'new'"...and should do the same as your original selector.

`filter` includes/excludes elements based on the result of the `return`. If `true` is returned, the element is left in the list. If `false` is returned, the element is removed from the list.

Using `.text()` is the same as what `:contains()` looks at, and `=== -1` means the text **isn't** found.

It might just be me, but I like to be more explicit with selecting elements, staying away from long selectors (especially pseudo selectors) and using jQuery methods instead. Although this might make your selections a little slower (not allowing jQuery to optimize native browser methods), it's easier to debug and looks cleaner to me than a big string (and hopefully works for you in all browsers).

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: filter is my last resort. Thanks for your answer but I am more interested in why IE throws the error. This is the first time I am facing a cross browser compatibility issue with jquery selectors.